# space inside tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes

Why is there no space between the `\x` number and the text in my `tikz nodes`? There is a space in the final one in which I manually inputted a number instead of using a forloop. That's what I'd like the rest of them to look like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz
{
\draw[gray, very thin, opacity=0.2] (0,0) grid (6,13);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 \node[right, rotate=90] at (\x,2) {\x I want a space between this text and the number before it!};
\node[right, rotate=90] at (6,2) {6 The space should look like this one!};
}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Regarding the duplicate things, I assumed that the problem had something to do with being inside of a `tikz` or `node` environment, so I thought it was different from the other threads that mentioned spacing.

Comment: Use `\x\ ` or `\x{} `, otherwise the space is "spent" to terminate the control sequence.